# How to get an access to ListFragment's arraylist from another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Got stuck with the following problem for a couple of days already. Here I'm passing String and position of a certain item in ListFragment to another EditFragment where the user can edit this String.

I'm using the following scheme for communication:

```
ListFragment --> Activity --> EditFragment.
```

In EditFragment I'm getting the clicked data from ListFragment out of the Bundle and store it in EditText where user can save it. How do I save it back to ListFragment? I believe I cannot use the bundle again, because when I try I get an error that the fragment is already active.

Here's my EditFragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_fragment_layout, container, false);
        editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        bundle = getArguments();

        position = bundle.getInt("position");

        editText.setText(bundle.getString("name"));
        return view;
    }

    //SAVE button do save data:
    save.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            //Here I need to save data back in ListFragment

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm really not sure if this will work but you can try it. I haven't tested yet.*
You'll need a callback in `EditFragment`, you should try to create [an `interface`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm) to trigger the update event of `String`.

Create an `interface` in `EditFragment`:

```
public class EditFragment extends Fragment {
    private EditCallback editCallback;

    public interface EditCallback {
        void updateItem(int position, String textUpdated);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        editCallback = (EditCallback) context
    }

    ...
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        editCallback = null;
    }
}
```

Then, trigger this method `updateItem(int, String)` when you want to update the item from `ListFragment`:

```
save.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // trigger the callback method
        if (editCallback != null) {
            editCallback.updateItem(position, editText.getText().toString());
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Thus, when a class will implements this `interface`, it'll call `updateItem()` overriding method. This is how `ListFragment` should use this interface:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements EditFragment.EditCallback {
    ...
    @Override
    public void updateItem(int position, String textUpdated) {
         // update the item's list by position,
         // call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter
         // do some stuff...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fllo! That totally makes sense! Now I don't get any errors. Just when I edit itemlist, press the Save button and then go back, my list stays unchanged( will post my code in a separate answer, could you please take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right solution would be to pass Intents and it should work ok for you (both for creating the EditText fragment instead of the bundle and later to pass the data back).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditTextActivity.class)
                .putExtra("position", position)
                .putExtra("name", name);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the fragment to extract data:

```
Intent intent = this.getActivity().getIntent();
int position = intent.getIntExtra("position");
String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but i'm getting an error: Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener, java.lang.Class<org.example.user.fragmentframework.EditFragment>)

Comment: nm, I should've used getActivity(), another thing is that it completely restarts my LisrFragment

Comment: @javastarter another way is to implement an Interface and pass data, then you won't need to restart your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my code here:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListFragment.Communicator{

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragContainer, myListFragment, "MyListFragment");

        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyListItemClick(String name, int position) {
        EditFragment editFragment = new EditFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("name", name);
        args.putInt("position", position);
        editFragment.setArguments(args);

        fragmentTransaction2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.fragContainer, editFragment);

        fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction2.commit();
    }
}
```

ListFragment:

```
public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment implements EditFragment.EditCallback {

    Communicator communicator;
    private MenuItem addItem;
    private MenuItem clearAll;

    ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
    String[] list2 = {"Sunday", "Monday",
            "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int randomNum;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        communicator = (Communicator) getActivity();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_fragment, menu);

        addItem = menu.findItem(R.id.add_string);
        clearAll = menu.findItem(R.id.clear);

        addItem.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                Random rand = new Random();
                randomNum = rand.nextInt(list2.length);
                list1.add(list2[randomNum]);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });

        clearAll.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                list1.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        String name = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        communicator.onMyListItemClick(name, position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(int position, String textUpdated) {
        list1.set(position, textUpdated);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public interface Communicator{
        void onMyListItemClick(String name, int position);
    }
}
```

EditFragment:

```
public class EditFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditCallback editCallback;
    MenuItem save;
    MenuItem cancel;
    View view;
    EditText editText;
    int position;
    Bundle bundle;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_fragment_layout, container, false);
        editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        bundle = getArguments();

        position = bundle.getInt("position");

        editText.setText(bundle.getString("name"));
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        editCallback = (EditCallback) context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.edit_fragment, menu);

        save = menu.findItem(R.id.save);
        cancel = menu.findItem(R.id.cancel);

        cancel.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                MyListFragment myListFragment = (MyListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyListFragment");

                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragContainer, myListFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItem menuItem = save.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                if (editCallback != null) {
                    editCallback.updateItem(position, editText.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Yor item was updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        editCallback = null;
    }

    public interface EditCallback {
        void updateItem(int position, String textUpdated);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to call a `Log` in `updateItem(...)` from `ListFragment`, just to be sure that this method is called? If it's working, maybe a little workaround can solve the issue: create a `public void updateList(position, String)` in adapter, pass the values to update, update the local (adapter's) list, `notifyDataSetChanged()` directly in adapter, and call this adapter's method `updateList()` from `updateItem()`.

Comment: Just logged the flow. It shows that editCallBack object is null, thus updateItem(..) is never called. Still working on this

Comment: I think I saw the problem. I attached the callback with `Context` which is the activity and not the list fragment. Just to be sure (again ;) ), could you try to implements `EditCallback` in the parent activity? if it's not that, I don't see it.

Comment: Oh, thanks, as I got it right you mean make my MainActivity implement EditCallback interface and updateItem() there?

Comment: Yes, to see if the Context in onAttach can update `editCallback` value and not setting to null.

Comment: Hmm, the object is still null, lol, this thing is crazy, not going to sleep till I figure this out))

Comment: I finally got it work))) as you suggested I implemented EditCallback in my MainActivity, but the actual implementation I did in ListFragment's activity. Then added editCallback = (EditCallback) getActivity(); in EditFragment's OnCreateView method.

Comment: So it finally works? This is a good news! From what you said, I'll update my answer.. But just to clearly understand, you keep to implement the callback on ListFragment and just change the callback initialization in EditFragment (using Activity instead of Context), aren't you?

Comment: Yes, It works! I passed editCallback = (EditCallback) getActivity(); to EditFragment's onCreateView and invoked updateItem for the Save button.  Then made MainActivity implement EditCallback interface with updateItem() method, but the actual implementation I delegated to the ListFragment, because I could get an easy access to this fragment's adapter's underlying data(arraylist). Thanks again!